# Laravel: Pass User's Notifications to All Members of Route Group

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a route group defined like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

  Route::get('/app', function () {
      //return the view...
  });
  Route::get('/calc', function () {
      //return the view...
  });
  Route::get('/fries', function () {
      //return the view...
  });

});
```

And I want to be able to pass in the user's notifications to all of these views with something like:

```
Notifications::all()->where('for', '=', Auth::user()->id);
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4, and I can't find any info for this online surprisingly. I have only come across ViewServiceProviders which I dont think is what I'm looking for.

Is it as simple as adding `->with(...)` to the end of my route group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any method of attaching the data to a route group all at once.  I would use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) to attach the data to multiple views as detailed in the "Attaching A Composer To Multiple Views" section.